# Bash: Grep between ""

Tags: bash, grep

i want to grep:

```
Orasidb11g_home1_2013_09_11_08_22
```

from

```
<HOME NAME="Orasidb11g_home1_2013_09_11_08_22" LOC="/u00/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.3/db_1" TYPE="O" IDX="9"/>
```

how can i do this ?
I try somethink like this:

```
cat test.xml | grep _2*** | grep db | egrep _[2***]
```

regards

Comment: What is `_2***` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a single line. You cannot grep only that keyword. Instead, this is what I think you want:

```
# echo '<HOME NAME="Orasidb11g_home1_2013_09_11_08_22" LOC="/u00/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.3/db_1" TYPE="O" IDX="9"/' | awk -F \" '{print $2}'
Orasidb11g_home1_2013_09_11_08_22
```

Comment: you should accept the answer (and optionally, upvote) if it answers your issue. That's how "Thanking" on StackOverflow works.

Comment: There is a risk in this answer - in XML, the properties - LOC, NAME, TYPE etc can be re-ordered; like: `<HOME LOC="/u00/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.3/db_1" NAME="Orasidb11g_home1_2013_09_11_08_22"  TYPE="O" IDX="9"/>`, in which case, it would fail. But if OP's input file format is fixed, this answer can anyway work.

Comment: My answer is based on the sample data provided by OP.

Comment: In this case is everytime the same order..

Comment: In that case, you can also use `cut -d'"' -f2`, instead of `awk`. AFAIK, `cut` should be faster than `awk`. (Sorry, if it sounds paranoid.)

Comment: Man .. so many speculations. Thanks. OP should have mentioned all these possibilities in his question so that I get an opportunity to improve my answer. In present situation, I do not wish to edit my answer.

Comment: `You cannot grep only that keyword`: wrong, use `grep -o`, short for `grep --only-matching`.

Answer (score 3):

Simple grep can also do this for you...

```
grep -oP '(?<=NAME=")[^"]*' test.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

why grep?

```
... | sed -e 's|[^\"]*\"\([^\"]*\)\".*|\1|;/Orasidb11g/!d'
```

prints only if first `""` contain `Orasidb11g`